# Integral calculation - Gravity - Free Fall

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

I have read this article https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/dont-heavier-objects-actually-fall-faster-because-they-exert-their-own-gravity.

In the best answer by David Z - there are some mathematical tricks I don't understand.

First there is the equation: 
$$\frac{G(m_1 + m_2)}{r^2} = -\ddot{r}$$

Then:

> So it's clear that when the total mass is larger, the magnitude of the
>   acceleration is larger, meaning that it will take less time for the
>   objects to come together. If you want to see this mathematically,
>   multiply both sides of the equation by r˙dt to get

$$\frac{G(m_1 + m_2)}{r^2}\mathrm{d}r = -\dot{r}\mathrm{d}\dot{r}$$

Up to this point I understand the mathematics but here is the problem:

According to the answer, by integration I should get $$G(m_1 + m_2)\left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_i}\right) = \frac{\dot{r}^2 - \dot{r}_i^2}{2}$$

---

**Question 1** What has been done now? $G(m_1 + m_2)$ is a constant so it stays the same. But: $$\int\frac{1}{r^2}dr= -\frac{1}{r}$$
Why is there the $\left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_i}\right)$??

---

**Question 2**
How write the right side of this equation $$\frac{G(m_1 + m_2)}{r^2}\mathrm{d}r = -\dot{r}\mathrm{d}\dot{r}$$ in a way like this: $$-\dot{r}= -1 \cdot\dfrac{dr}{dt}$$
*I don't know what to do with $\mathrm{d}\dot{r}$*.

---

**Question 3** Why is $$\int -\dot{r}\mathrm{d}\dot{r}= \frac{\dot{r}^2 - \dot{r}_i^2}{2} $$

*I don't really get the steps that are not written there.* To me it seems that the equation could also be written as $$\int -x \,\mathrm{d}x= -0.5 x^2$$ Now the answers are not the same.

---

**Question 4**

> $$G(m_1 + m_2)\left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_i}\right) = \frac{\dot{r}^2 - \dot{r}_i^2}{2}$$ Assuming $\dot{r}_i = 0$ (the objects start from relative rest), you can rearrange this to $$\sqrt{2G(m_1 + m_2)}\ \mathrm{d}t = -\sqrt{\frac{r_i r}{r_i - r}}\mathrm{d}r$$

What has been done right know?

How is $$\dot{r}_i = 0$$ related to $$- \frac{1}{r_i}$$?

I don't get this at all.

---

I know that the derivation goes on but in my opinion it doesn't make sense trying to understand the rest if I haven't got it until here. 
My mathematics knowledge is that of the European equivalent of "academic high school".

It would be really cool to get some helpful answers.

I have already started with: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/index.htm but I haven't come that far yet.

Nevertheless I am willing to understand this derivation.

**Question 5** What is the best way to learn such things like my question. Shall I continue with OCW or shall I do something else?

Comment: I don't know if you get any answers to this heap of questions but as a hint start with: The integrals are not indefinite and you evaluate them as the difference of the primitives at the upper and lower bounds, this should answer at least two parts.

Comment: In physical term, the limits of integration are related to initial and final condition. So for the question $1$, it is written as
$$
\int_{r_i}^r\frac1{r^2}\ dr=\frac1{r_i}-\frac1r.
$$
The same idea is applied to the question $3$
$$
\int_{\dot{r}_i}^{\dot{r}}\dot{r}\ d\dot{r}.
$$
For question $2$, multiply the first equation by $dr$ and then rewrite $\ddot{r}$ as $\dfrac{d\dot{r}}{dt}$.
It should be easy if you notice that $\dot{r}$ means $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$. For question $3$, if $\dot{r}=0$, then $r$ is a constant.

Comment: I have been thinking about Question2: $$\dfrac{d^2r}{d^2t}=\ddot{r}=\frac{dr\cdot dr}{dt \cdot dt}$$

Then if i multiply both sides with $\dot{r}dt$ this right side of the equation should become: $$\frac{dr \cdot dr \cdot dt}{dt \cdot dt}\cdot \dot{r}$$ Then two $dt$ cancel each other and the result is $$\dot{r}\cdot\frac{dr\cdot dr}{dt}=\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r}\cdot d{r}$$

Is this right? 


And: Is the following true?: $$\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r}\cdot d{r}=\dot{r}d\dot{r}$$ What was my mistake?

Comment: The mistake is
$$
\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}\neq\frac{dr}{dt}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}
$$

Comment: ok, of course it is not.

@Tunk-Fey - Could you explain to me the following:

$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2r}{dt\cdot dt}$$ Is this true?


And by far more important: 
How to get from 
$$\ddot{r}\cdot\dot{r}\cdot dt$$
 to $$\dot{r}\cdot d\dot{r}$$ 

???


And what does $d\dot{r}$ exactly mean?

Comment: You have
$$
\frac{G(m_1 + m_2)}{r^2} = -\ddot{r}
$$
Multiplying both sides by $dr$ yields
$$
\frac{G(m_1 + m_2)}{r^2} dr= -\ddot{r}\ dr
$$
Rewrite $\ddot{r}$ as $\dfrac{d\dot{r}}{dt}$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{G(m_1 + m_2)}{r^2} dr&= -\frac{d\dot{r}}{dt}\ dr\\
&=-\frac{dr}{dt}\ d\dot{r}\\
&=-\dot{r}\ d\dot{r}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Now it is quite clear. Is the following true?: $$\dot{r}\cdot dt = dr$$